# vb6 windows application migration to silverlight/wcf web application

Tags: silverlight, wcf, vb6-migration

we have existing vb6 win application for gaming industry. There are mainly 3 big modules. For 1st module/part, I converted vb6 code to vb.net library. I used that vb.net library in wcf duplex service to use existing business logic and get/set data. And, this wcf service, I use in silverlight application. 1st part was dealing with much calculation, so I didn't convert vb6 code to c#, instead I converted to vb.net. Even, old vb6 code has hard-coded sql queries instead of calling pre-compiled stored procedures. I kept the same in vb.net library.

Now, client wants to convert entire system to silverlight web app. And, so I am thinking that for rest of the 2 modules, I should convert vb6 code to c# as there is less calculation and more db operations. Also, I will clean up code to use stored proc instead of hard-coded queries.

So, plz let me know
if my approach is correct or not. What can go wrong here? What things I should take into consideration before processing further ? should I manually convert vb6 to c# ? I know there is tool for vb.net to c# conversion, but don't know about vb6 to c#. Any advice on migrating code from win app to service oriented architecture ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why convert to C#? VB.NET is just as good.

Answer (score 2):

The tools that take VB.net to c# are far from perfect, so I highly doubt that going from VB6 to c# is going to be painless. One of the beautiful things about .NET is the fact that it allows easy integration of components regardless if their original programming language. So there shouldn't be any problem migrating your old code to VB.net (easy, cheap), componetizing it and writing new code in c#.

You need to ask yourself: What is the business value/benefit to your customers if the code happens to be in C# rather than VB.NET?

Performance, reusability, maintainability, etc. of a mature codebase is not likely to be significantly different with C# vs VB.net. I would bet that converting your mature code to c# rather than vb.net will introduce more problems than it will solve.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using these tools http://www.artinsoft.com/visual-basic-6-or-csharp-to-the-web.aspx
They migrate from VB6 to Silverlight and WCF services